# Rectangle touch sides of another rectangle

Tags: xna, c#

I am making a platformer game and im trying to make the player collide with all the blocks, here's a picture:
[image: My game]

The blocks is stored in List and im trying to get the side's of the block usin

```
static class RectangleHelper
{
    public static bool TouchTopOf(this Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    {
        return (r1.Bottom >= r2.Top &&
                r1.Bottom <= r2.Top + (r2.Height / 2) &&
                r1.Right >= r2.Left + r2.Width / 4 &&
                r1.Left <= r2.Right - r2.Width / 4);
    }

    public static bool TouchBottomOf(this Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    {
        return (r1.Top >= r2.Bottom &&
                r1.Top <= r2.Bottom + (r2.Height / 2) &&
                r1.Right >= r2.Left + (r2.Width / 4) &&
                r1.Left <= r2.Right - (r2.Width / 4));
    }

    public static bool TouchLeftOf(this Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    {
        return (r1.Right <= r2.Right &&
                r1.Right >= r2.Right - r2.Width  &&
                r1.Top <= r2.Bottom - (r2.Width / 4) &&
                r1.Bottom >= r2.Top + (r2.Width / 4));
    }

    public static bool TouchRightOf(this Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    {

        return (r1.Right >= r2.Right &&
               r1.Right <= r2.Right + r2.Width &&
               r1.Top <= r2.Bottom - (r2.Width / 4) &&
               r1.Bottom >= r2.Top + (r2.Width / 4));
    }
}
```

I got this code from a Youtube video and i changed it a little bit.. (the original code didnt work well)

the problem im having is:
the TouchBottomOf & TouchRightOf functions doesn't work well...(The collision occur randomly, sometimes on top of the block, sometimes little below it (TouchBottomOf), same with TouchRightOf)

Is there a better way to check it?
thanks.

Comment: Does`A.TouchLeftOf(B)` means that A touches the left side of the B rectangle or that the B rectangle touches the left side of the A rectangle?

Comment: @RoyT. it means A touches the left side of B.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good way to check for overlap between two rectangles, but your code has a few bugs.

In the code you posted, the only function that works the way I would expect is TouchBottomOf. That function will return true if `r1` is overlapping the middle part of the bottom half `r2`.

[image: TouchBottomOf]

`TouchTopOf` will return `true` when `r1` is above `r2` and NOT overlapping it (not touching it, but within 1/2 of `r2.Height`).

[image: TouchTopOf]

`TouchRightOf` and `TouchLeftOf` will never return `true`. Each of them requires `r1` to be both below `r2` and above it; This can never be true if your rectangles are more or less normal (Top >= Bottom).

Comment: Actually the TouchRightOf and TouchLeftOf does work but i have bugs on TouchRightOf for some reason.
I will try to fix the other functions based on your answer.

Comment: Ah, I think I was confused. I assumed that the Bottom of a Rectangle would be less than the Top. If the opposite is true, then my answer is kind of "backwards." TouchRightOf and TouchLeftOf look very close to correct, and it's TouchBottomOf that is testing an area that's outside of the second Rectagle, not TouchTopOf.